# How to generate Random number in Jmeter with prefix and store it into variable

Tags: performance, variables, jmeter, performance-testing

I am using JMeter's Function Helper Dialogue and i found below syntax -

**Syntax** - ${__Random(12,99,customer-id)}

**Result** - random values b/w 12 to 99 getting generated, which will get stored in variable "customer-id"

Now Problem is I have to generate value with prefix 'test' (say-test12) and store it in variable 'customer-id'

How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why would you need this because [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) can be normally concatenated with plain text so if you need `test12` just use `test${customer-id}` statement where required.

However if you really need to generate some static text followed by a random number you could go for [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) configured like:

```
${__groovy('test'  + org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(12\,99),customer-id)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [RandomUtils JavaDoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomUtils.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)